# Cygwin X applications do not launch

Tags: emacs, cygwin, gedit

I have a problem with Cygwin X, in that applications don't seem to run.

If I try to run `gedit`, or `emacs`, the applications seem to just return `0` immediately:

```
me@mycomputer ~
$ gedit &
[1] 10244

me@mycomputer ~
$ emacs &
[2] 10976
[1]   Done                    gedit
```

Similarly, if I try to start either of these applications from the X Applications Menu on the taskbar, they don't launch.

The Cygwin log file shows the following, indicating that the application started, and then exited straight away:

```
(xwin-xdg-menu:13896): GVFS-WARNING **: Error creating proxy: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gtk.vfs.Daemon: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)

executing 'xterm -title '/home/mj3/.xsession-errors' -e less +F /home/mj3/.xsession-errors', pid 8080
(pid 8080 stderr) xterm: cannot load font "-Misc-Fixed-bold-R-*-*-13-120-75-75-C-120-ISO10646-1"
executing 'gapplication launch org.gnome.gedit', pid 9288
pid 9288 exited with status 0
```

Any ideas? It's driving me nuts! I've tried a fresh install of Cygwin, with the same results.

Comment: First: have you run `cygcheck -c` to verify all package are complete? What is the output if you run `startxwin` from Cygwin Terminal ?

Comment: cygcheck -c shows a big long list of packages, and all of these have status "ok".

Comment: Is there a way to include the output from startxwin here? There aren't enough characters allowed in comments! (Sorry, I'm new to this site).

Comment: You need to extract any relevant error. Questions: Are you using a 32bit or 64bit cygwin ? What is the output of `cygcheck -c| wc -l` ?

Comment: I'm using 64-bit Cygwin. The output of your command is as follows:      $ cygcheck -c| wc -l
    298

Comment: Running startxwin, the only messages that sound like they could be errors are those below:
    (II) xorg.conf is not supported
    LoadPreferences: /home/mj3/.XWinrc not found
    LoadPreferences: Loading /etc/X11/system.XWinrc
    MIT-SHM extension disabled due to lack of kernel support
    XFree86-Bigfont extension local-client optimization disabled due to lack of shared memory support in the kernel

Comment: The problem is not there. I also have something similar. The best way to support you is to use the cygwin mailing list, see https://cygwin.com/problems.html . Subscribe and send a mail with the problem, attach the cygcheck.out and the `/var/log/xwin/XWin.0.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the next guy with similar problem, the culprit was the anti virus Trend Micro OfficeScan.:

```
With AV disabled, everything seems to work fine.
```

http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2018-07/msg00278.html